# How to change navigation item title with "username"?

Tags: json, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I want to change my controller's navigation item title with username. I am using JSON data struct for user information (username, userid, etc..) and I write a method Code like below but it isn't working for me.can anyone help me ?

```
var usersInfo: HomePageUserInfo? //this is my user information struct


fileprivate func setNavItems () { // this function is calling in viewDidLoad.
    let naviuser = usersInfo?.username

    navigationItem.title = naviuser
}
```

Comment: tried adding : 
Try the following in viewDidLoad

self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"

Answer (score 0):

See if your viewController is extend by UIViewController then you can change the title text by using -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.title = "some title"
}
```

And if it's UINavigationViewController then use -

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"
```

Comment: Controller is UICollectionViewController but I can change title text with manually. I checked with debug and I guess I can't fetch username from server any idea about that ?

Comment: I thought you debug that otherwise first I ask you about it. Leave it show me how you save the user info.